# Make website page size normal desktop size in mobile devices

Tags: android, html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am mid-way through re-coding my current site and I have come across a mobile compatibility problem.

If you view the current website via mobile device ([here](http://mobiletest.me/#d=iPhone_5_portrait&u=http://fantasyfifaleagues.net/)) you can see the width and height of the website is normal sized as it would be when viewing on a desktop with the ability to scroll vertically and horizontally.

However, on my new site (using bootstrap slate from bootswatch - bootswatch.com/slate/) when you preview it on a mobile device it tries to squeeze it all into the fixed mobile device width ([here](http://mobiletest.me/#d=iPhone_5_portrait&u=http://xbox360.fantasyfifaleagues.net/))

I have tried adding the lines below, however I don't see a difference.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,  minimum-scale=1.0"> 

html,
 body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Is there any way to make the new site to be shown in the same dimension as the current one in mobile devices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is the responsive behavior of bootstrap I guess. And imho it definitely makes sense to fit the content into the device width on mobile devices.

You can read about disabling the responsive feature in your bootstrap project here: [Disabling bootstrap responsiveness](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)

UPDATE:

To make your content horizontally scrollable add:

```
html, body {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

to your stylesheet.

If this doesn't work try adding `!important`to the declaration:

```
html, body {
    overflow: auto !important;
}
```

**NOTE:**
This is not the most efficient way css-performance wise, but given your comprehension level of CSS, I guess it would be too much for your to alter the bootstrap.css yourself.

Comment: When I configure bootstrap to be non-responsive, I am then unable to scroll horizontally on the webpage in a mobile device, any ideas on what I should do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap it self the steps on disabling responsiveness are below. You can download template/CSS with this disabled. Check out http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Steps to disable page responsiveness
Omit the viewport  mentioned in the CSS docs
Override the width on the .container for each grid tier with a single width, for example width: 970px !important; Be sure that this comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the !important with media queries or some selector-fu.
If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding behavior.
For grid layouts, use .col-xs-* classes in addition to, or in place of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid scales to all resolutions.
You'll still need Respond.js for IE8 (since our media queries are still there and need to be processed). This disables the "mobile site" aspects of Bootstrap.